# Admin panel and User panel in nodejs application

Tags: node.js

I am making Student management web application system and I have already made front-end side of web application.
I am going to make admin panel which controls, create, delete, update, post and register new students in server side and students log in and visit web page, but can not register, Only admin can register new students. Additionally Admin have login and password. 
1. How to separate admin panel and front-end web application .
2. How can admin itself register if admin panel works on web app in the internet because someone might visit that page, register and will be admin.
3. Is it possible that Admin panel works locally and can save data into MLAB database and front-end web application can read that saved data from MLAB database.
Thanks for any advice

Comment: You have to establish some sort of trust model for how to establish who is an admin or who can be an admin.  Typically, there's some sort of site admin that can establish who other regular admins will be and then those regular admins can handle the students (three levels of permission).  There's no reason that they can't all work off the same web UI and when they log in, your web app knows what types of permissions they have and only allows them access to the appropriate operations for their permission level.  In some cases, you make a separate admin login page for admins to log in there.

Comment: what if admin forgets login and password? If I make registration link there as well, someone might visit that page, register and will be admin

Comment: You never just make an admin page that allows anyone to become an admin.  That's just not how security or trust models work.  Most systems today design a password recovery system that lets you put in your email address (and optionally perhaps one other piece of known information) and then the username and a new password will be sent to that email address (if that email address is associated with a registered user).  At some point, somebody has to have master access to the system.  It could be someone who has physical access to the server and can edit a config file or something like that.